# How to insert a script between react native tags

Tags: reactjs, react-native, tags

I am building a two columns style list (2*x). where it fills buttons from an  API.

I am trying to add to the second column an if condition (if data in null skip creating a button)

Please advise on how to add an if condition between tags.

In render

```
  Elementlist.push(
    <View style={styles.RowElement}>
      <View style={styles.Column}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("elementDetails")}>
          <Text>{state.elementID[x]}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.Column}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("elementDetails")}>
          <Text>{state.elementID[x + 1]}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>)
  x = x + 1;
  if (this.state.UnitsID[x + 1] == null) { break; }
}
```

In return

```
      <ScrollView>
        {Unitslist}
      </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React Native FlatList component has already this feature with numColums property.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#numcolumns

So you can easily apply to your case.

A sample:

```
import React from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, View, FlatList, StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

const DATA = [
  {
    id: 'bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abb28ba',
    title: 'First Item',
  },
  {
    id: '3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbd91aa97f63',
    title: 'Second Item',
  },
  {
    id: '58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72',
    title: 'Third Item',
  },
    {
    id: '58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d73',
    title: 'Fourth Item',
  },
];

function Item({ title }) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.item}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        numColumns={2}
        data={DATA}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <Item title={item.title} />}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 10
  },
  item: {
    backgroundColor: '#f9c2ff',
    padding: 20,
    marginVertical: 8,
    marginHorizontal: 16,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 16,
  },
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. In other cases I still need to add conditions for example such as (if data != null, insert the tags) . So how can I add for if condition between tags.